# Want to calculate Goodputs and End to End delay in Omnet++ INET

Tags: omnet++, inet

So i'm creating an adhoc network of vehicles. The wireless nodes are configured with UdpBasicApp. I want to calculate Goodputs and end to end delay. Unfortunately i'm getting zeros in end to end delay and can't figure out the way for goodput (not throughput). Since it is written that "The received packets are discarded" on the omnet website on UdpBasicApp. Therefore on application layer, only sent packets are there.. not the received . For example
node[0].app[0].packetSent..... = 345
But
node[0].app[0].packetreceived..... = 0
However
node[0].udp do receive something...

The ini file is as follows:

```
[General]
network = RoutingScenario
sim-time-limit = 10s
debug-on-errors = true
cmdenv-express-mode = true
image-path = ../../../../images


## UDPBasicApp
*.node[*].numApps = 1
*.node[*].app[0].typename = "UdpBasicBurst"
*.node[*].app[0].destAddresses = "10.0.0.72"
*.node[*].app[0].destPort = 5000
*.node[*].app[0].messageLength = 256B
*.node[*].app[0].sendInterval = 0.25s
*.node[*].app[0].packetName = "UDPData"
*.node[*].app[0].startTime = uniform(1s, 2s)

# Ieee80211Interface
*.node[*].wlan[0].opMode = "p"
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.bandName = "5.9 GHz"
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.channelNumber = 3
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.transmitter.power = 100mW
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.bandwidth = 10 MHz


# HostAutoConfigurator
*.node[*].ipv4.configurator.typename = "HostAutoConfigurator"
*.node[*].ipv4.configurator.interfaces = "wlan0"
*.node[*].ipv4.configurator.mcastGroups = "224.0.0.1"



# VeinsInetMobility
*.node[*].mobility.typename = "VeinsInetMobility"
*.node[*].mobility.speed = normal(8mps, 0.01mps)

# VeinsInetManager
*.manager.updateInterval = 0.1s
*.manager.host = "localhost"
*.manager.port = 9999
*.manager.autoShutdown = true
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("osm.launchd.xml")
*.manager.moduleType = "vanettutorials.veins_inet.VeinsInetRoutingCar"


**.vector-recording = true
**.scalar-recording = true
**.statistic-recording = true


# Routing
**.router = "Aodv"
```

Answer (score 0):

With UdpBasicApp, the received packets are discarded, but the statistics are recorded (throughput, endtoenddelay, number of received/sent packets, etc).

The throughput recorded by UdpBasicApp is goodput (as in application-level throughput).

Comment: The endtoend delay is giving zeros for all node. Also the throughput seems odd.... like 500bps for 50 seconds. 600bps for 60 seconds. Don't look like true values